# Oracle Apex 23.1 - Date Picker - changing week number column name

Tags: oracle-apex

After migrating the application from Apex 18.2 to 23.1 and upgrading Date Picker controls to the modern version I've encountered a problem with setting a custom name for the week number column (the default is "WK" and I need "KW" for Germany).

I'm pretty sure, that this can be done by setting a proper custom attribute, I just don't know it's name and Oracle doesn't provide any documentation for this or at least I can't find any.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

P.S. Since the control underneath the Date Picker has changed somewhere between Apex 18.2 and 23.1, calling this when the page loads doesn't work anymore:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "weekHeader", "KW");
```

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, you can try styling the week title using CSS

```
.a-DatePicker-weekColumn span[aria-hidden] {
    visibility: hidden!important;
}
.a-DatePicker-weekColumn span[aria-hidden]:before {
    content: "KW";
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
}
```